# What to do for Autohotkey functions that not available on Autokey

Tags: autohotkey, autokey

I want to migrate my AHK code to Autokey code for Ubuntu (AHK code monitors clipboard and mouse movements, performs advanced string processing and paste it to the specific window).

There are many functions like OnClipboardChange, StringReplace, RegExReplace, GetKeyState, etc. on AutoHotKey which are not available on AutoKey. What to do for these? Do I need to Python code these? If yes, then how?

PS: Basically, I want to migrate from Windows to Ubuntu. I use advanced scripting of AutoHotKey on Windows. But I cannot find any comparable scripting program on Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Most i miss in Ubuntu is MouseClickDrag

Answer (score 1):

I have never used it but it looks like IronAHK has some things you are looking for. Its a AHK rewrite in a .NET framework which allows it to run on all operating systems. Here is a link to the AHK forum with more information.

https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/50354-ironahk-alpha-cross-platform-net-rewrite-of-autohotkey/